# td nth child(1) is not working properly when sending e-mail through Power Automate

Tags: html, css, power-automate

```
    Table {
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: #EEEEEE.
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    }

    Table td, Table th {
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      padding: 1px 3px;
    }

    Table th {
     font-size: 12px;
     font-weight: bold;
     padding-top: 10px;
     padding-bottom: 10px;
     text-align: left;
     background-color: #1C6EA4;
     color: white;
    }

    Table tr td:nth-child(1) { 
      color: #ff0000; 
    }
```

But E-mail i receive never shows the color i input. i already checked that it worked when i input the code on Web-based HTML CSS try editor.
What is the problem of below CSS code?

Comment: Be very careful when using pseudos, many clients use old HTML renderers that make mince meat out of emails. Check here for pseudos: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/selectors/nth-child/ not a lot of support there. Also check here: https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=nth-child

Comment: Did you try checking the email in another email client?

Comment: Actually not yet in another client but only Outlook. I tried your code , but still table does not shows color at first column. Is there a problem with nth-child(1) code?